# Reescribir una url ya reescrita en .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Necesito reescribir una url ya reescrita por el CMS en el que trabajo.
El caso es que las reescribe mal y las deja bastante feas.

La url que quiero reescribir es:

```
http://whatever/foo/offer/?offer_id=1213/
```

La beauty url que quiero tener:

```
http://whatever/foo/offer/1213/
```

he probado muchas cosas, pero no me funciona ninguna, como:

```
RewriteRule ^offer/(.*)?$ offer/offer_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^offer/(.*)?$ offer/?offer_id=$1 [QSA]
```

etc.

Cómo debería hacerlo?
Debería pelearme con el plugin y tratar de editarlo o hay alguna solución en .htacceess?

Comment: Cual es de hecho el valor real del URL? Probablemente: `http://whatever/foo/offer.php?offer_id=1213`. Por favor prueba esto:
RewriteRule `^offer/([0-9]+)/?$ offer.php?offer_id=$1`

Comment: No, la url ya está tratada por un plugin del cms. No hay .php.